# Hiding phone number being called through iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-telephony

I want let users make calls through my app. Is there a way to hide the number being called, so that the privacy is protected?

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to [research a bit more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caller_ID)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this is possible, as it could be used for malicious purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the privacy of the person making the call to be hidden, you can use a *67 prefix on the number when you dial. Basically, just add *67 to the beginning of the number. Most US carriers support this.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to hide the caller id. Sorry, my question was not very clear. Is there a way to hide the number that is being called? As in I am calling 555-555-5555, but cant see it on the phone app.

Comment: That's against many guidelines. Can you tell us what use you would make of it that is not malicious?

Comment: @gcatalfamo: What guidelines? The phone companies support this; they built it into their system. They didn't set out to create a "prank call feature". Use it for marketing calls, calls to individuals who you don't want to give your number to, making a call from any phone who's number you want to protect, etc. I get that privacy is a double edged sword. But any feature CAN be abused, but it's beyond the scope of an app to attempt to govern morality.

Comment: Interesting enough, many Toll Free services include a "deep caller ID" system that can pick up the caller's number even if they use *67. So for example attempting to call a bill collector on a toll free number using *67 to hide the number may not work.

Comment: @jwatts1980 my reply was directed to user1964921's comment. Not yours...